# Validate Number in Javascript not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, validation, firefox

This validation return true when the input text is 0 to 10 (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10). 
The backspace do not work in Firefox ,in Google Chrome ,Internet Explorer work well.I tried to enable the charcode of the backspace but the problem persist.
How can I make it works in firefox ?

I have this:

```
<script>
function compruebacampo(evt, campotexto)
{
    var charCodeOfZero = 48;
    var numberJustEntered = evt.charCode - charCodeOfZero;
    var fullString = campotexto.value + "" + numberJustEntered;

    var matchesOne = false;
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        if (fullString == ("" + i)) 
            matchesOne = true;
    }

    if (!matchesOne)
        return false;
}
</script>


<input type="textbox" onkeypress="return compruebacampo(event,this)" >
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: "The keypress event is fired when a key is pressed down and that key **normally produces a character value**" -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress

Comment: I know people will yell at me for using it for such a little case but it's such easier and cross-browser : why don't you use jQuery ?

Comment: ok,I keep in mind @elclanrs

Answer (score 1):

I was going to write a function that used browser-specific cases (via `navigator.userAgent`), but I figured that was too clunky and complicated. I think the easiest thing to do is to bind an event handler to that specific input and have it listen to the `keyCode`s (`key`s in FireFox). This method also avoids inline JavaScript, which is definitely a plus.

```
event.keyCode < 58 && event.keyCode > 47
```

For non-FireFox browsers, this captures all the digits (`0-9`).

```
event.key > -1 && event.key < 10
```

In FireFox, this will capture all the digits (`0-9`), since the above will fail.

```
event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 0
```

Captures backspaces and allows them to go through.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="numberInput">
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById("numberInput").onkeypress = function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode < 58 && event.keyCode > 47 || event.key > -1 && event.key < 10) {
        /* nothing */
    } else if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 0) {
        /* nothing */
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

I tested in Safari, FireFox, and Chrome. It worked in all three for me. I'm sure you could rewrite those booleans to just one `if` block.

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/SbJXV/8/)

Comment: thanks for your help,but I need only the 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 not all the numbers.any idea please

Answer (score 0):

Try this alternative which will allow only numbers to be input on the field: http://jsfiddle.net/6faHh/

```
function compruebacampo(e, campotexto) {
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help,but im lookin' for validate only the 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 not all the numbers.any advice please

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('input').keypress(function (e) {    
 if ($(this).attr('id') == "txtBoxId") {
                        regex = new RegExp("^[0-9\b]+$");
                        var charString = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
                        if (regex.test(charString)) {
                            return true;
                        }
                        else {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
}
```